# Weblogic is going in unknow state

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am using the weblogic 10.3.6 with Java 7.

My application is developed in Primefaces and Spring.

After a successful start-up, weblogic is going into an unknown state and the application is no longer accessible. Admin Console also become very slow.

I found below message in console and logs:

```
<1601815382043> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 192.168.201.51:37,516 during the configured idle timeout of 25 secs>
```

Please let me know what is the possible cause and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: This message is a warning and is not the root cause of your issue. Do you see any error message inside the server's log just before the server is going to unknown state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the https configuration from server. Now server is fine on http protocol as my external load-balancer still https

Answer (score 1):

This alarm log is not a problem error log. Please restart the application and see if there is any change in the log. If there is a change, please provide the error log for further tracking and analysis.